# jQuery catch Captcha image before loading OR get the image file content after loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, vbscript

so i play a game which verifies user input after some time by sending a captcha form. Since the captcha image changes with every reload, i have to get the contents of the loaded image, or if possible, have some listening function to catch the image before being rendered by the browser (to prevent re-newing the image).

```
    <form action="?" method="post">
    <img src="captcha.url?token" id="captcha_img">
    <input type='text' name='captcha' id='captcha_text'>
    <input type='submit' name='sendcaptcha' value='Continue'>
    </form>
```

With the content or link i plan on sending it through a vbscript which executes a captcha breaker program and return the code, this i have all figured out, i'm stuck on getting the image..
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does the captcha change every time the url in `img` tag `src` attribute is loaded, or does it depend on token? If it doesn't change every time you load the image itself, you can get the image src and wget the image to feed it to your script. Happy spamming!

Comment: It changes everytime is reloaded, it doesn't depend on the token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out too:

```
    function addListener() {
        $(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
            if($('#captcha_img').length!=0){
                $(this).unbind('DOMSubtreeModified');
                var src = $('#captcha_img').attr("src");
                $('#captcha_img').attr("src", 'caught.png');
               alert(src);
        }
        });
    }
```